# regex optional using allowTypes in primefaces

Tags: java, regex, primefaces

here is my regex, in local java, it works, but when im trying to put it on p:fileUpload allowTypes it doesn't work.

my goals are
1) "itrs" or "ITRS" is a must
2) "-draft" or "-DRAFT" is optional
3) ".csv" or ".CSV" is a must

i want to filter the filename and file extension as much as possible

this is working on my local:**(itrs|ITRS)((-draft|-DRAFT)?)(\.|\/)(csv|CSV)$**

Comment: Basically, you need to use the regex pattern within regex delimiters. See my answer below. In your requirements, you do not mention that there can be `/` before `csv`, hence I do not use it in the main regex, but I added a note at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either

```
allowTypes="/^(?:itrs|ITRS)(?:-draft|-DRAFT)?\.(?:csv|CSV)$/"
```

or, if `dRaFt` and `ItRS` are also accepted, you may shorten the pattern a bit using `i` case insensitive modifier:

```
allowTypes="/^itrs(?:-draft)?\.csv$/i"
```

Note the use of `/` regex delimiters here. Also, see an example in [PrimeFaces *"FileUpload - Single"* docs](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) illustrating the use of regex delimiters.

**NOTE**: If you really need to match `.` or `/` before `csv`, replace `\.` with `[.\/]`.

Comment: hi Wiktor, if it is okay with you, May you please explain what happen in your regex here in full details? including why do i have to note the use of "/" thanks in advance Wiktor.

Comment: @Applegate That is *your* regex, I only added [**regex delimiters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters). `i` is a case insensitive [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) (as I already wrote). `(?:...)` are [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) (only used to group patterns, not to save and keep submatches).